# Graph theory: spanning tree diameter

Tags: graph-theory

> For $2 \le k \le n − 1$, prove that the $n$-vertex graph formed by adding one vertex adjacent to every vertex of $P_{n−1}$ has a spanning tree with diameter $k$.

I know that the diameter of a tree is the length of its longest path from an example in my text (West), so that gives me length of $n-2$ in this path before I add one vertex. So does adding a vertex that connects to each of the edges extends the length of the path by $1$?

Answer (score 3):

This is what the graph looks like in the $n-1=9$ case:

[image: n-1=9 case]

A [spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree) is a subgraph that is both (a) a tree and (b) contains every edge.

Here's an example of a spanning tree in the above graph:

[image: An example spanning tree]

There will be many others.  The task set in the question is to find examples of spanning trees of diameter $d$ for $d \in \{2,3,\ldots,n-1\}$, for all $n \geq 1$.

---

*Hint*: The brown edges in the following diagram illustrate examples of spanning trees of diameter $2,\ldots,6$, respectively, in the case $n-1=6$.

[image: n-1=6 case]

I suggest you try to generalize this construction.  (Note the diameter $n-2$ case is special.)

Comment: Suppose we label the added vertex x and label the vertices on the original path v_1, ..., v_n-1. Now choose a spanning tree from x to one of the endpoints of P_n-1, either v_1 or v_n-1. Then the diameter of the spanning tree would be <= n-1. Actually, it seems to me that it would be n-1.

Comment: (Choosing a spanning tree from $x$ to one of the endpoints of $P_{n-1}$ doesn't really make sense.)  A spanning tree is a subgraph that is (a) a tree and (b) contains every vertex.  So, in the above illustrations, we delete the pink edges to get a spanning tree.  But there will be many other spanning trees I've not listed.

Comment: I am so sorry; I did not state my intent very well. I want to choose a spanning tree that begins at x and travels through each vertex, ending at an endpoint, so the path would be x, v_1, v_2, ..., v_n-1. (Or you could begin with x, v_n-1, ... and go the other way). In your picture, the final spanning tree is the one I had in mind.

Comment: Yes, that's one spanning tree, and it has diameter $n-1$ (but that still leaves the diameter $2,\ldots,n-2$ cases open).

Comment: Ah, then one could create spanning trees as follows: an x,v_2-path would have diameter 2, an x,v_3-path would have diameter 3, and so on until an x,v_n-1-path which would have diameter n-1.

Comment: They would be subgraphs that are trees, but they wouldn't be spanning trees (every vertex needs to be included).

Comment: Create the first spanning tree by creating a path from x to v_1 by traveling through each v_i from v_n-1 to v_1. This tree will have diameter n-1. Next, create a path from x to v_1 by traveling through each v_i from v_n-2 to v_1 and create a path from v_n-2 to v_n-1. This path will have diameter n-2. From here on, create paths from x to v_1 by traveling through each v_i from v_n-k to v_1, 2<=k<n-2, and by creating a path from x to each v_i for any v_i not contained in the previous path. These trees will have diameters n-3, n-4, …, 2. We have a spanning tree with diameter k for 2 <= k <= n-1.

Comment: @PhiB: Yes, that’s the scheme that Rebecca had in mind. Do you see why diameter $n-2$ can’t be handled the same way as the smaller diameters?

Comment: Actually, no, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: It's a bit sly (I fell for the trap myself originally).  But if we attempt to do it that way for $n-2$, we end up with a spanning tree which is a path of length $n-1$ (and thus has diameter $n-1 \neq n-2$).  So we need to find another construction in that case.

Comment: Ah!!! I do see it now. Thank you for pointing that out. NICE!